# Google OAuth verification process is not clear

Tags: google-oauth, google-fit

During Google OAuth verification process, Google requires some actions, that are not clear, since only links have been provided with general content as shown below:

1. Comply with Limited Use requirements ([link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#limited-use-reqs))
   Ensure you have met all Limited Use requirements
2. Update brand information ([link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#general-verification-process))
   Ensure that your app's name, logo, and OAuth clients meet all requirements

The requested scopes are the ones below:

```
fitness.activity.read
fitness.activity.write
fitness.sleep.read
fitness.sleep.write
```

We retrieve data (sleep, activity) from another API (Fitbit) because users use fitbit bands and we need to add this additional data in Google fit to have a detailed activity/sleep summary. Also, the data we read (sleep, activity) is saved in a mobile's local db and also in a cloud server.

Is there anything wrong with this process? Privacy policy is aligned with this flow and also users give their consent.

Asked Google for more details regarding Limited Use requirements but never got an answer, although it is mentioned to ask via email in verification thread, if something is not clear.

Any help on this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `although it is mentioned to ask via email in verification thread` - then please do. We'll help you fix your code issues, but we can't (and won't) provide a support line

Comment: I have already asked in their email thread but no answer on this. That's why I wanted some further help if possible. Is legal advise the only solution here? Technically I have no issues with the code, just lack the Google OAuth verification

Comment: Why would you need legal advice? But that aside; StackOverflow is for helping devs with issues in their code, please read the [tour] (tour page), [ask] (how to ask), [help/on-topic] (on topic)

Comment: Also, `Is there anything wrong with this process?` - this tends to lead to opinions on different peoples best practices, none are technically right or superior (unless you have obvious holes), but opinion topics are also off-topic

Comment: Thank you @CanO'Spam for your replies. Since I got no answer from google, I thought it would might be helpful (since google fit developers page promotes it) to post here if anyone else had/has same difficulties. I guess if I get a more clear view of what is needed and turns out to be a code issue I will update the thread.

Comment: For completeness, I sincerely hope you find an answer to your question, but that said; I'm flagging this question because it concerns third-party product support (rather than how to write code for that product), which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow/255746#255746) for more information. You should contact the company for support using their service.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.